Windows Form - CefSharp automatically resizes window on monitor 125%
I have 2 monitors: the main monitor has 125% of zoom (laptop display), the second one is a secondary monitor that has a standard zoom of 100%.
Now i have a Winform application (.NET Framework 4.8) using DevExpress that use an embedded CefSharp browser and as soon as the embedded browser loads the specified url, i can see a blink of that windows form and the zoom of that windows form become "according to the second monitor" (100% zoomed).
How is it possibile? And how can I prevent this behaviour?
I read that DPI awareness could be involved in this issue. Is it possibile?
But for a simple reason (Application is quite old and a quite full of features to maintain) my application cannot consider DPI awareness, so i accept to see a pixeled imaages.
So, can I avoid the behaviour described below of CefSharp browser?
Thanks in advance to all!
I have tried to set the DPI Awareness (PerMonitorV2) with DevExpress and with with "classical windows form way" (app.manifest) but the font and layout become too big (or too small) and it is not "automatically" resized to 100% then to 125% alternatively.

The way to set DpiAwareness in .NET Framework 4.8 is through app.config, not app.manifest (not forbidden, but not straightforward and supported as in the former). See the notes here: DPI Awareness - Unaware in one Release, System Aware in the Other in case you want to test different methods OR disable automatic DpiAwareness introduced by WPF elements in a DPI-Unaware WinForms app

See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/4410
